# Возвращения значения елемента this

Tags: javascript, html

Есть меню

```
  <li class="menu" id="2" onmousedown="selectProductsOnCategory(this)">
            <a href="#" >плуги</a>
                <ul>
                    <li class="menu" id="3" onclick="selectProductsOnCategory(this)">
                        <a href="#">Оборотные плуги</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menu" id="4" onclick="selectProductsOnCategory(this)">
                        <a href="#">Загонные плуги</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
        </li>
```

И есть скрипт

```
function selectProductsOnCategory(e) {

console.log(e);
}
```

Почему при нажатии на плуги `е` возвращает 1 елемент который нажат(как нужно). А при клике на оборотные плуги или загонные возвращает 2 елемента(тот по которому нажали и парент(плуги)). И как сделать что б он возвращал 1 елемент?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При нажатии на "плуги" срабатывает `onmousedown="selectProductsOnCategory(this)"`,
а при нажатии на "Оборотные плуги" или "Загонные плуги" срабатывает `onclick="selectProductsOnCategory(this)"` и `onmousedown="selectProductsOnCategory(this)"` одновременно, так-как клик по вложенному элементу считается и кликом по родителю. Чтобы это предотвратить используйте `event.stopPropagation();`

Comment: @Miki извините, но разве это не работает только с jQuery? потому что вставив в начало функции event.stopPropagation(); ничего не поменялось

Comment: Вам надо вставить в вашу функцию `e.stopPropagation();` Будет выглядеть вот так:` function selectProductsOnCategory(e) { e.stopPropagation();
console.log(e);
}`

Comment: p.s и в js stopPropagation() есть и без jquery

Comment: @Miki возможно я туплю, но зделав так `e.stopPropagation();`  выдает ` Uncaught TypeError: e.stopPropagation is not a function`

Comment: @ItsMyLife, это потому что ты вызываешь функцию _selectProductsOnCategory(this)_ - а `this` в этом случае будет элементом li, а у него нет метода stopPropagation

Comment: @Mikl, решение не подойдет просто потому, что **разные** события.

Comment: @Mikl ,Grundy спасибо огромное, поменяв на одинаковые события все работает!

Comment: `stopPropagation` останавливает текущее событие, но не другое. Если события разные, он не поможет. В некоторых случаях может помочь `preventDefault`.